# Тем более, что мне известна причина расторжения. Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая и почему?
Я никак не пойму этих конструкций.

Comment: Запятая не нужна в данном случае, так как имеет место единая пояснительная конструкция.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, трудность вызвана смешением союза ТЕМ БОЛЕЕ ЧТО и союзом ТЕМ БОЛЕЕ (в значении 'к тому же').

- Синтаксические конструкции, начинающиеся с союза «**тем более что**», выделяются знаками препинания. При этом первый знак препинания обычно ставится перед составным союзом (перед словом «тем»), а не между его частями. Для примера: *Она охотно приняла приглашение, тем более что слышала об этом доме.* (Ф.Искандер, Молодой архитектор и красотка). *Это известие всех школьников страшно взволновало, тем более что наша дорога в школу проходила мимо реки…* (Д.Мамин-Сибиряк, Дурной товарищ). *Мне, сударыня, доктора велели ноги в тепле держать, тем более что мне сейчас нужно идти настраивать рояль к генеральше Шевелицыной.* (А. Чехов, Сапоги). Как видно из примеров, речь идет о сложноподчиненных предложениях.
- Союз "**тем более**" употребляется в значении 'к тому же'. Обычно этот союз вводит присоединительные придаточные предложения (тоже СПП). Синтаксические конструкции с этим союзом выделяются знаками препинания, обычно запятыми, например: *Почему я вел себя неприлично в их глазах, тем более даже сам чувствовал, что веду себя невоспитанно, безвкусно, провинциально?* (А. Битов, Молчание слова).

Кроме того, в художественных текстах встречается употребление сочетания «тем более» в качестве вводных слов: *Тем более, от тифа сейчас нам большая угроза.* (Л.Кассиль, Кондуит и Швамбрания). *Мне, тем более, домой скоро.* (В.Короленко, Чудная). (Информация с Грамоты.ру, Справочник по пунктуации). На мой взгляд, это как раз ваш случай (по приведенному контексту сужу). Я бы поставила знаки препинания так: "*Тем более, что мне известна причина расторжения*" или "*Тем более, мне известна причина расторжения*".

Comment: Если честно,то довольно тяжело понять разницу.
Все очень ымуторно,но за ответ спасибо :)

Comment: Ваш случай - не сложноподчиненное предложение. Поэтому первый и второй пункты не годятся. Но для более точного анализа не помешал бы более широкий контекст ;-)

Comment: Предыдущее предложение нужно обязательно. Вполне возможно, что это придаточная часть СПП, оформленная как самостоятельное предложение.

Comment: Оно выглядело так:"Я не буду искать каких-либо доказательств против него, тем более(,)что мне и так известна причина расторжения договора".